# Changes to a .php file not getting compiled

Tags: php, event-observer, cache, class

I made some changes to the file `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Observer.php`.
However those changes are not reflecting in `includes/src/__checkout.php` in the `Mage_Checkout_Model_Observer` class.(After flushing all the magento caches)

In fact, I put some obvious errors in the `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Observer.php` file (removed the closing bracket of the class), still did not get any error anywhere from the website.

Why is magento ignoring changes I make to a php file?

Comment: As a good practice I highly suggest that you keep the original `app/code/core` file and copy it to `app/code/local`. This way your changes won't be overwritten when you upgrade your Magento instance.

Comment: Will magento automatically use the files in app/code/local instead of app/code/core or I will have to point to the new location manually somewhere?

Comment: No Magento Will automatically uses them as long as you respect the path. In your case the file will have to be under`app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Model/Observer.php`